# Stripe, is it possible to search a customer by their tax_id?

Tags: stripe-payments

**Is there a way to go back to the customer id, knowing the value tax_id?**

I am trying in this world but without success:

```
$customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(["limit" => 100, "tax_info" => ["tax_id" => "01234567890"]]);
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
  echo 'ID: ' . $customer->id;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible - Stripe only allows searching customers by id [or by email](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, then I will have to iterate the customers with the foreach cycle and then retrieve the id.